# error when base64String arrived from android to nodejs via socketio

Tags: java, android, node.js, socket.io

i work on an app who will send image from android to nodejs via socket io and i got this error when i send data who has size like 700,00 KB in node js and i don't know how to someone can help me to work it better ???
This is my java code

```
File myFile = new File (selectedImagePath);
            int ficher = (int) myFile.length();
            System.out.println(""+size(ficher));
            int file_size = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(myFile.length()/1024));
            System.out.println(""+file_size);
            size(ficher);
                FileInputStream imageInFile = null;
                try {
                    imageInFile = new FileInputStream(myFile);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }  
                byte imageData[] = new byte[(int) myFile.length()];
                try {
                    imageInFile.read(imageData);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                // Convert to base64;
                String imageDatastring = Base64.encodeToString(imageData, SELECT_PICTURE);
            socket.emit("img", imageDatastring, "MAK", "MAK");
```

And my javascript code (node js) is here

```
socket.on('img', function(msg, usr, username){
console.log(' Message from : '+username+' \n Message is : '+msg+"\n to : "+usr)
console.log(usernames[usr])
console.log(usernames)
io.sockets.socket(usernames[usr]).emit('event', msg, username);

      fs.writeFile(username+ "- to -"+usr+'.png', msg, "base64", function(err){if(err){console.log(err)}})
```

});

This is error i got

```
AAAL9wOAGFzc2V0cy9z\nZXR0aW5nc2NyZWVuLnBuZ1BLBQYAAAAAmQCZAMgnAACf/w4AAAA\n","243
810840505","apk","23:10"]}
debug - emitting heartbeat for client ig4QpjbTaEgr20jOs6IA
Assertion failed: end <= source_len, file src\smalloc.cc, line 280
C:\xampp\htdocs\socketio_android-master\socketio_android-master>
```

I use socket io version 0.9.16
Thanks to all!!